# Adding constants to be used across node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a constants.js file I am using with my node application with the content being a list of exports like so:

```
exports.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'myapp.sid';
exports.SESSION_STORE_DB_PATH = 'mongodb://someip:someport';
exports.API_GATEWAY_URL = 'http://someurl:someport';
```

So I can just include my constants.js file in other files and reference the properties easily enough:

```
var consts = require('../constants.js');

module.exports.something = function() {
    var tokenUrl = consts.API_GATEWAY_URL;
}
```

I'd like to have some status enums in my constants.js file as well, so something like:

```
exports.STATUS = {
    DRAFT: 'DRAFT',
    LIVE: 'LIVE',
    EXPIRED: 'EXPIRED'
};
```

But I'm wondering if this really is the best way to be storing constants.

Are there other ways? What about using `const` and having this added to a global scope?

Comment: To make them real constants you might want to call `Object.freeze` on each (nested) object to avoid overwriting any of them later in the code (strict mode will throw an error if you try to assign something to them again).

Comment: I think your approach looks good, the only thing I would say is some of those constant's look more like configuration settings. eg. ESSION_STORE_DB_PATH , so I personally would place them in a configuration file, maybe in JSON/YAML or even javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, apart from some of these looking more like configuration settings than constants.. You could also simplify your exports a tad.

Instead of having lots of exports.*,

```
module.exports = {
   SESSION_COOKIE_NAME: 'myapp.sid',
   SESSION_STORE_DB_PATH: 'mongodb://someip:someport',
   API_GATEWAY_URL: 'http://someurl:someport',
   STATUS: {
      DRAFT: 'DRAFT',
      LIVE: 'LIVE',
      EXPIRED: 'EXPIRED'
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Keith, also +1 about the config file, its something I have been considering doing for a little while now :)